# A shorthand for Function.prototype.call.call?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

### Ways to call a function

Consider this simple function:

```
function my(p) { console.log(p) }
```

I can call it like this:

```
my("Hello");
```

And also like so:

```
my.call(this, "Hello");
```

Moreover, this is possible:

```
Function.prototype.call.call(my, this, "Hello");
```

---

### A shorthand for the functional way

I am interested in the last option - the most functional one, but since it's too long I tried to make a shorthand:

```
var call = Function.prototype.call.call;
```

in order to call my like this:

```
call(my, this, "Hello");
```

But I get this TypeError:

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined
```

Anybody knows, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say

```
var call = Function.prototype.call.call;
```

the last `call` loses its actual context. You need to explicitly say that the `call` belongs to `Function.prototype.call`.

You can do that, by creating a new function, which actually binds it like this

```
var call = Function.prototype.call.call.bind(Function.prototype.call);
call(my, this, "Hello");
// Hello
```

The `bind` function returns a new function, which when invoked will have the context (`this`) set as `Function.prototype.call`.

Answer (score 4):

`call`, presumably, makes use of `this` internally.

By calling it without context, you've changed the internal value of `this` from something that has access to the function prototype to `window`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do that, then consider this (if you have an ES5 compliant interpreter):

```
var call = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.call)
```

The [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function makes sure that the *context* (the `this` variable) while making the function call is `Function.prototype.call` instead of `undefined`, as you see in your case.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. I found out now, that with underscore-js I could also write: _.bind(Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.call) - I am asking myself if there might be something like "bindSelf" to archive that.. it's rather a new thread..