# Difference between Function.call, Function.prototype.call, Function.prototype.call.call and Function.prototype.call.call.call

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototype, call

I have checked many similar questions on stackoverflow, such as [call.call 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889321/a-shorthand-for-function-prototype-call-call) , [call.call 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074664/javascript-function-prototype-call), but I am a newcomer, and I cannot make comment anywhere. I hope I can  find a comprehensive and thorough explanation of how the JavaScript interpreter execute these functions, with opening a new question here.

Here are some examples:

```
function my(p) { console.log(p) }
Function.prototype.call.call(my, this, "Hello"); // output 'Hello'
```

The above example is a standard usage of Function.prototype.call, which is easier to understand. my understanding is: 'my' as an function object executes its inherited method 'Function.prototype.call' ie. my.(Function.prototype.call) => my.call(this, 'Hello')

```
Function.call.call(my, this, "Hello") // output 'Hello'
```

I am confused here, in comparison with the above example. I do not know how JavaScript interpreter works here. 'my' sees Function.call and Function.prototype.call as same method?

```
Function.prototype.call(my, this, 'Hello2') // output nothing
Function.call(my, 'Hello2') // output nothing
```

I cannot explain why this statement does not throw an error? In fact, I do not know how Function.prototype.call as a method works.

```
Function.prototype.call.call.call(my, this, "Hello3"); // output 'Hello3'
```

I cannot explain how the JavaScript interpreter interpretes the above statement? interpreting 'call' from right to left? then what does my.(Function.prototype.call.call) mean?

```
Function.prototype.call.call.call.call(my, this, "Hello4"); // output 'Hello4'
```

why I can put any number of '.call' here, and the output is the same? Does not each call consumes an argument as 'this' object, which should imply only three arguments are not enough? a similar question as the immediately above one

Then more examples:

```
var $ = Function.prototype.call
$(my, this, 'Hello5') // Exception: TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible Proxy
```

why it does not output nothing, just as one above example?

```
var v = Function.prototype.call.call 
v(my, this, 'Hello6') // Exception: TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible Proxy
```

Does it mean, when use variable v, then JavaScript interpreter tries to interpret v isolatedly, without seeing there are arguments following? Then the interpreter thinks the 'this' is global variable 'window'? I do not know how the interpreter works differently between v() and Function.prototype.call.call()

Can anyone help, please? Thanks!

Comment: `Function.prototype.call.call === Function.prototype.call // true` `Function.call === Function.prototype.call.call  // true`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are strictly equal, but can you please explain why their outputs are different when they are followed by the same arguments in parentheses?

Comment: Haven't I done it in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

`Function.prototype.call.call(my, this, "Hello");` means:

Use `my` as `this` argument (the function context) for the function that was `call`ed. In this case `Function.prototype.call` was called.

So, `Function.prototype.call` would be called with `my` as its context. Which basically means - it would be the function to be invoked.

It would be called with the following arguments: `(this, "Hello")`, where `this` is the context to be set inside the function to be called (in this case it's `my`), and the only argument to be passed is `"Hello"` string.

As soon as your `my` function does not use `this` context in any way - you can pass anything:

```
Function.prototype.call.call(my, 123, 'Hello2') // outputs "Hello2"
```

As soon as `Function.prototype.call.call` refers to the same function as `Function.prototype.call.call.call` (and `Function.call` and `my.call`) and so on, you can add as many `.call` property accesses as you want and it would not change anything.

As of your second question:

```
var $ = Function.prototype.call
$(my, this, 'Hello5')
```

does not work, since the context for the function call is set dynamically during call (unless it's bound with `.bind()` or is an ES2015 arrow function).

So when you invoke it as `$` the context is not set explicitly (since it's a variable, not an object), so by default it's set to `undefined` or the global object (depending on how you run your code).

Comment: When I invoke a function variable, why JavaScript interpreter does not translate $ into Function.prototype.call.call, and then see $ is followed by an object within parentheses? It can find the 'this' object this way. So I still do not know how the function is executed here.

Comment: It does not, because that's how the standard tells the interpreter to work: the context is determined during a function call. And `$(...)` does not carry any context.

Comment: Should I refer to the ECMA-262? If so, which section, please? I am not quite clear of the conception of context. "when you invoke it as $ the context is not set explicitly", you mean, the _**this**_ is not set explicitly?

Comment: @nlite that's correct. It is `this` that is not set in that case. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation see the item 5

Answer (score 0):

Every object is linked to a prototype object. When trying to retrieve a property that does not exist on an object, its prototype object will be looked up. 
[Read more](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/).

`this` is a special variable available in JavaScript functions. Its value depends on how you call the function, not how you define it (with some exceptions). [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

As you can see, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is defined on `Function.prototype` which means all function objects will have access to it. It is a special function in that it allows you to explicitly set the value of `this` when invoking a function.

One common usage is calling array functions on array-like objects, which don't inherit from `Array.prototype`:

```
function f(){
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
    // `args` is now a real array with all the privileged functions.
}
```

---

To get back to your examples,

```
function my(p) { console.log(p) }
Function.prototype.call.call(my, this, "Hello"); // output 'Hello'
```

Here you are calling `call` on `Function.prototype.call`.

It is the equivalent of

```
function my(p) { console.log(p) }
my.call(this, "Hello"); // output 'Hello'
```

Since `call` is defined on `Function.prototype`, and it is itself a function, when you call `call` twice, you are retrieving the same function. That's why you can chain them indefinitely.

```js
function my(p) { console.log(p) }
const call1 = Function.prototype.call;
const call2 = Function.prototype.call.call;    // Same as `call1.call`.
const call3 = my.call;

console.log( call1 === call2 );
console.log( call1 === call3 );
```

---

Now to the second part of the problem. How `this` works inside functions. [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

The thing to remember is that its **value is determined dynamically, based on how you call the function, not how you define it** (with some exceptions).

When you do this, the `call` function's `this` value will be whatever it is in the current scope (when in global scope, it is `undefined` in strict mode and `window` in loose˙).

```
var v = Function.prototype.call.call 
v(my, this, 'Hello6') // Exception: TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible Proxy
```

That's why you're getting the error, `this` is not a function, as `call` is expecting it to be. When you call a function from an object, `this` will refer to
that object, and that's what happens when you call `call` on some function (functions are objects too).

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this question because mentally I had a hard time making the leap from 'this' being a parameter that is then treated as sort of a pseudo-object from which the call method is called from. I summarized my understanding (in Nodejs):

```
function f(a) {console.log(a);}

f.call(global, 1);
//function reference to be called = f
//context to call it from = global
//parameters used when invoking = 1
//equivalent call => global.f(1)

Function.prototype.call.call(f, global, 1);
//function reference to be called = Function.prototype.call
//context to call it from = f
//parameters used when invoking = global, 1
//equivalent call => f.call(global, 1)
```

References used:

[A shorthand for Function.prototype.call.call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889321/a-shorthand-for-function-prototype-call-call)

[Javascript Function.prototype.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074664/javascript-function-prototype-call)

[Can't use Function.prototype.call directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490211/cant-use-function-prototype-call-directly/44490793#44490793)

[a is a function, then what `a.call.call` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916477/a-is-a-function-then-what-a-call-call-really-do)